# Is it possible to apply two different scalers to one dataframe?

Tags: cluster-analysis, scaling, data-preprocessing

Is it possible to apply two different scalers to one data frame? Or is there any side effect?

I have a data frame with a left skewed distribution. In addition, the characteristics of each feature are greatly different, and the value is also greatly different.

Finally, we wanted to do clustering, and we thought of the following solutions for data frame preprocessing.
First, log scaling is applied for data distribution correction.
Second, minmax scaling is applied to unify the size unit of the feature.

The order of the two tasks is not important, but I wonder if there will be no problem applying the two scalers.

Thank you.